# if body tag has class 'home' via child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, child-theming

I'm trying to simply show content with a php `if statement`.

I would like to add a footer element (*to the footer.php*) for the homepage only.

So, `if` body tag has class '`home`'; then add new footer element. I'm trying below; but currently nothing is displaying at all.

```
$classes = get_body_class();
if (in_array('home',$classes)) {
    function lastUpdated() { 
        echo '<div class="last-updated">Last Updated:<span class="date-update"></span></div>'; 
    }
}
```

the above code is in my child theme's `functions.php` file;

Answer (score 0):

First of all, how WP will know, where you want to output that markup?
To solve this question you can use hooks, you need to monitor parent theme for such code `do_action('before_theme_footer')`, to find place where you can "inject" your code.
And then you can apply your output to this hook, and inside callback function check if you on home page with `is_front_page()`:

```
function footer_markup(){
  if( is_front_page() ) {
    echo '<div></div>';
  }
}
add_action('before_theme_footer', 'footer_markup');
```

You can read about hooks here - https://designmodo.com/wordpress-hooks-filters/

If no any hooks in footer.php, you can copy footer.php to child theme and add your code in the right place where you want to output it:

```
if( is_front_page() ) {
  echo '<div></div>';
}
```